# Python Extending Classes with Same Method Name

Tags: python

In Python if you have a class that extends 2 or more classes, how does it know which class method to call if they all have a method titled **save**?

```
class File(models.Model, Storage, SomethingElse):

    def run(self):
        self.save()
```

What if Storage has a **save()**, and what is SomethingElse() has a **save()**?
Can anyone briefly explain?

Comment: Someone made a post that had a really good answer then deleted it!

Comment: In practice, you'll want to write your own `save` which replaces or calls the base class methods.

Comment: I am new to Multiple Extending and I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it.. However, this is a nagging question on my mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Python supports a limited form of multiple inheritance as well. A
>   class definition with multiple base classes looks as follows:
>
> class DerivedClassName(Base1, Base2, Base3):
>       
>       .
>       .
>       .
>
> **The only rule necessary to explain the semantics is the resolution rule used for class attribute references. This is
>   *depth-first, left-to-right***. Thus, if an attribute is not found in
>   DerivedClassName, it is searched in Base1, then (recursively) in the
>   base classes of Base1, and only if it is not found there, it is
>   searched in Base2, and so on.

So in your example if all 3 classes have method `save` instances of `File` will use method `save` from `models.Model`

Comment: That makes sense, very interesting.. What if Base1 had a save() and you wanted to access Base2's save()? Is that possible?

Comment: @JREAM Yes, this is why you pass a baseclass to `super`.

Comment: depth-first, left-to-right really only applies to old-style classes.  new-style classes that's approximately right, but not exactly.  You can look at the `__mro__` attribute to see the actual method resolution order.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh!!!! Thank you @Marcin that makes sense so like:  `super(Base2, 'param').save()`

Comment: @Marcin -- That's not exactly a time for `super`.  `super` will call `Base1.save` also (assuming that everything else uses `super` properly).  Ultimately, if you *only* want to call Base2.save, you need to do so explicitly:  `Base2.save(self,args)`

Comment: @mgilson `super(Base2,self).save()` will do it.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, when this occurs, you'll likely want to write your own `save` which either replaces or uses one of the base class methods.

Let's say you want to just call them:

```
class MyFile(models.Model, Storage, SomethingElse): #file is a builtin class. Confusion will abound

    def run(self):
        self.save()

    def save():
        super(Storage, self).save() # start search for method in Storage
        super(models.Model,self).save() # start search for method in models.Model
```

NOTE HOWEVER that if the `mro` (see: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) of `models.Model` doesn't contain a `save`, and `Storage` does, you'll end up calling the same method twice.

A fuller exploration is here: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ (and now linked to from the official docs).